# How can I view Nikon RAW files as I transfer them to my Windows computer?

Tags: nikon, software, raw, windows, nikon-d5100

When I download my raw (Nikon NEF) files from my camera I just connect a USB cord that came with my camera and download the files off of the card. My question is, is it possible to view the files I am downloading. Currently my screen looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of RAW Files in Windows]

While I do not mind no thumbnail view it would be nice to at least see the file numbers. JPEGs show the thumbnail but no file name. Is it possible to get both?

Few Notes: I am using the [FastPictureViewer Codec Pack 3.2](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/), so I can view RAW files in Windows. These files also do not display in Adobe Bridge. I am on Windows XP and using a Nikon D5100. Once I transfer files from camera to local hard drive the raw files view without issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea why you aren't seeing the file names—I use the "classic" views (rather than the task-based native XP version), and I can see the file names regardless of the view mode (tiles, thumbnails, list, details, etc.).

You will need to download and install [the Nikon NEF codec](http://nikonimglib.com/nefcodec/) to get thumbnails outside of your photo management/editing software. Note that I see thumbnails in Thumbnails view only; I get an Adobe application icon in Tiles view. Also, the thumbnails are never rotated, at least on my system, so shots taken in portrait orientation will be laid over on their sides in Explorer.

Comment: Hmm, I will have to do a bit more digging to see what else I find, I have the NEF Codec installed (using FastPictureViewer Codec Pack). And I also use classic views. Thanks for your help.

Comment: After a bit more digging, if I change my view from Thumbnail to List I can at least see the file names, however the thumbnails will not view even with the codec installed. This will work though, thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: One final note here, I was connecting the computer directly to the computer. If I use a card reader the files view as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Picassa supporting NEF now. But if you have Nikon camera, you should have free ViewNX 2 software, where NEF is supported of course.